# How to deploy officeJS addin on office online on-premise server?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, office-js, sharepoint-online

I have written a small officeJS addin for excel which run perfectly on desktop excel client. Also office online from onedrive gives an option of installing the addin from the ribbon menu. I want to use this officeJS addin to run on either of the following configuration:

1. On premise office online server configured with on premise
   sharepoint server.
2. On premise office online server with my own
   implementation of wopi host.

How to deploy an officeJS addin on office online on premise server which is preferably managed centrally by the administrator.

Also why is the add-ins option is not available on the office online configured with sharepoint, pfa image:
[office online onedrive v/s office online onprem with sharepoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87jOI.png)

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The Office Online Server currently doesn't enable Office store by default. As part of the configuration, you'd have to enable it. I'm not 100% sure about the exact setting. It may be this: set the `AllowExternalMarketplace` flag to true.

More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622920(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Note that you can also use corporate catalog option if you use SharePoint inside your environment (WOPI host)

Comment: Do you have any link explaining the procedure in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. On a server in the farm, open the **SharePoint Management Shell** (PowerShell). Run this command:

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm - OfficeAddinEnabled:$true
```

You probably have to be logged in as a farm administrator.
There is some documentation here: [Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219442(v=office.16).aspx)